# Excel Import using SSIS cuts off at 999,999 rows. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, webi

OK, my first question here ever and at least to me, it's a puzzling one.

Importing .xlsx file with 1,048,576 rows. I confirmed the number of records visually. When I tried to import it using SSIS and also using openrowset in SSMS, it's only importing/reading 999,999 rows. I am using ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver and have tried to run the SSIS package in both 32- and 64-bit but no difference so far. SQL server is 2012. Excel file is exported out of SAP BW so I can't really confirm the version but it's .xlsx format.

Below is the openrowset command I am using in SSMS (SSIS package is harder to describe) :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as [Rows] 
FROM  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=\\....\...\SALES_DATA.xlsx; HDR=yes; IMEX=1','SELECT * FROM [CO_SALES$]')
```

When I execute the above command in SSMS, I get 999,999 and I expect 1,048,575 (excluding header.) Anyone has any insights to why this may be happening? I don't really see anything obvious about any of these rows where they might be failing... I know Excel files can be a pain compared to CSV and cause a lot of strange issues but has anyone actually imported more than 999,999 records from a single Excel file(worksheet) successfully?

TIA,
Brian

Comment: Make another 1+mil sample file with different data and see if the exact same thing happens. If not, it is a problem with your file. If all 1+mil files hit that cap, it is an SSIS issue.

Comment: I can't say I've ever had this issue; and I import a lot of files daily via SSIS packages. `OPENROWSET` and an SSIS Dataflow Task are nothing alike. This smells more like a configuration error (but what, i have no idea, as we don't have anything from the SSIS package to work from).

Comment: @dfundako:  Thanks for the idea. I created a test file with 1,048,575 rows and openrowset command does count all rows. So it must be the way SAP BW is exporting these excel files that is non-standard, which is not surprising. I didn't test with SSIS but I am fairly sure that is the cause since they exhibit similar symptoms.

Comment: Isn't the maximum number of rows in a sheet equal to 999,999?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits In Excel 2007 and later: `2^20`; before that, `2^16`.  I don't know of any version where it is 999,999

Answer (score 0):

This requires a code correction on SAP BW in order to get more than 999999 records. The easiest way to do this is to upgrade BW to latest Support Package. Below I've added the minimum SP required for each BW version in order to get the full set of records.

BW-Version and minimum Support Package needed:

7.3 -           SP15

7.31 -          SP18

7.4 -           SP15

7.5 -           SP3

You can also manually make the code correction but unfortunately I cannot share with you the exact steps, If you have access to SAP Notes search this '2198828' for the solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: EJB, can you elaborate on what you mean when you say code correction is needed to get more than 999,999 records?   At the moment, those Excel files (exported by SAP BW) do have more than 999,999 records (1,048,575 data rows); issue here is that SSIS or SQL openrowset sees only the first 999,999 rows. When I open those files and save it again, then SSIS/SQL sees the full 1M+ rows. Will this issue be corrected by the "code correction"?  I will go and look up the notes now. :)

Comment: You will need to make sure that the files being exported by BW are the same as when you check it before transport. There is a limitation in the code of method read_data that sets the amount of records to precisely 999,999. The code correction changes that logic to get the total number of records to be read. If you are 100% certain that at the point of export you see more than 999999, then I would say the code correction will not solve it, instead you need to investigate at SSIS side like your integration configuration if there is any limit to records pulled per run.

Comment: Thanks for the input, EJB. I don't think it's SSIS or any configuration because when I open and save the Excel files (without making any changes), it works fine (meaning it sees all 1M+ rows.) Also, I created a new dummy Excel file with different data structure and 1M+ rows,  SSIS/SQL have no issues. It leads me to believe that SAP/BW's XLSX format is doing something odd beyond 999,999 records. I will have to find workarounds somehow..not sure what... maybe open and resave Excel files within SSIS package